# Why is jQuery dropping divs when parsing html strings

Tags: jquery

As shown in this [simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamiltont/axz9b0bc/), the following code outputs the `<p>I am inner content</p>` but seems to drop the div tag. What am I missing?

```
var x = $('<div id="#testing"><p>I am inner content</p></div>');
alert(x.html());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) returns the innerHTML of `x`.

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

Youn eed to get the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML)

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).prependTo($log)
  }
})();

var x = $('<div id="#testing"><p>I am inner content</p></div>');
log(x.prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, ok! Small followup question if you have time...why do I have to use `.prop` to get at the outer HTML? Is there a reason jquery seems to be encouraging programmers to use the innerHTML? I don't even see an official function .outerHTML

Comment: PS - I'll accept this once stackoverflow allows me. I've timed out from too much use :-P

Comment: @Hamy there is no jQuery utility method for getting outer html, it is a dom property([Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML))... [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is used to read dom element properties

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/axz9b0bc/1/)

```
var x = $('<div id="#testing"><p>I am inner content</p></div>');
alert(x.prop('outerHTML'));
```

outerHTML is similar to innerHTML, it is an element property that
includes the opening an closing tags as well as the content.